# Google images/videos search

Tags: javascript, html, google-search

I have a Google search bar in my website, which I created with this:

```
<form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q"/>
</form>
```

If I write into the search box *`stackoverflow`*, it performs a search in Google with this URL:

> https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow

Now, I wanted to modify this to perform a search directly in **Google Images** or in **Google Videos**. Note that in order to perform the search *`stackoverflow`* in Google Images/Videos I just need to use these URLs:

> Images: https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow**&tbm=isch**
>   
>   Videos: https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow**&tbm=vid**

How can I add the parameter `tbm` to the search using HTML/Javascript?

Comment: Use a hidden input `<input type="hidden" name="tbm" value="isch" />`

Comment: thanks @pete! I had already tried that and wasn't working, so I asked here... but now it's working! I can't guess what I did wrong before because it's too easy :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use an nother form elemet. here i used an select box:

```
<form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q"/>
    <select name="tbm">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="isch">Images</option>
        <option value="vid">Video</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: please, would it be possible to change your code to have 3 different buttons -one for each search type-, instead of select box?